# Make a basic animation/translation by touch up inside a custom cell

Tags: image, swift, animation, label, transition

I'd like to apply basic animation to some elements in my custom cell, such as label, image: in particular I'd like to make these animation start also when I touch up inside a cell. I'm a beginner and I only learnt to use animateWithDuration and transitionByView: is it possibile to add my aim with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom cell class override the touchesEnded event and put the animation inside that

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        // your code
    }];
}
```

This will fire at the same time as you'd expect touchUpInside to happen

Comment: thanks you so much @RyanOfCourse! now I cannot try, but as soon as I get home I'll do. If you would like, here there is a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32376856/how-to-change-an-uiimageview-into-a-custom-cell